# What is the difference between "acquisitional", "acquisitive", and "acquisitory"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

I am actually a native speaker, but this one threw me.

"Acquisitory" seems to be associated with avarice/greed, possibly specifically for material goods.

"Acquisitive" also seems to be related to the desire to acquire more material things, but possibly less pejorative.

"Acquisitional" seems to be the most neutral of the three, pertaining simply to the act of acquiring, without the connotation of greed.

Could anyone confirm or clarify?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acquisitive and acquisitory are essentially complete synonyms. Both describe an avaricious interest in acquisition.

Acquisitional means of or relating to acquisition with no additional connotation.